# Change size of element more precisely in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm working on Xcode version 4.4. Couldn't find the way how to change element's(UIView) size more precisely in storyboard. I can drag anchors of element, but It's difficult when elements are small. 
Is there any way to change width and height of element by one pixel?

EDIT: Development environment is iOS(not Mac OS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit a view's position and size in the Size Inspector.  Select the view you want to modify, then from the menu bar choose View > Utilities > Size Inspector.

[image: size-inspector]

Comment: oh, thank you. [View] Properties were just closed by triangle. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, you should be able to use the inspector to edit the object's properties.

Check out this link, specifically point 7: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_quick_start/020-Tutorial_Designing_a_User_Interface_with_Interface_Builder/interface_builder_tutorial.html